# Overview of virtualizing interrupts with Intel VT-x

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, x86, virtual-machine

I'm trying to allow code running in non-root VMX mode to send IPIs from one core to another using an xAPIC. I'm implementing this functionality in both the VMM and the guest OS. I'm having difficulty getting this to work, and after spending hours reading through documentation, I wanted to reach out to see if anyone could point out any obvious flaws or help to consolidate some helpful info.

Here is my understanding:

In the EPT, I should map all guest physical address accesses to the memory-mapped APIC registers to the host physical base address of the memory-mapped APIC registers. Thus, when I try to write to the APIC registers in the guest OS, they will go to the APIC registers. To my understanding, since the CPU is in non-root VMX mode when this occurs, the APIC knows to virtualize these interrupts.

Next, when an IPI is received, a VM exit occurs with the exit reason `EXIT_REASON_EXTERNAL_INTERRUPT`. The VMM should then look through the ISR to find the bit set that corresponds to the received interrupt. Next, I inject the interrupt into the guest OS.

I think I'm sending IPIs correctly, or at least what I wrote above seems to be working properly. However, I'm having difficulty receiving IPIs. When I look through the ISR, no bit is set. Does anyone have any suggestions? I am using Intel Xeon CPU E5-2630, but I set the x2APIC to use the xAPIC interface by setting the `nox2apic` kernel parameter.

Comment: I'm in the process of writing an answer, but in the meantime can you show the values of the VM execution controls (Pin, Primary, Secondary, VM-exit). (In particular I'd like to know the value of bit 15 of the VM exit controls.)

Comment: Sure thing - I just headed out for a bit (on my phone right now) but I’ll post these soon. Thanks!

Comment: @prl The output of vmcs_read32(VM_EXIT_CONTROLS) is 0x36fff, which does not have bit 15 set. I am not using KVM - there is a kernel module called Dune which allows you to run a process in VMX non-root mode so that you can better manage some hardware features in your process (http://github.com/ix-project/dune).

Comment: @prl I'm mapping the APIC page as described in my question because this is the way that it is done in the code in the repo I just linked. What is the proper way of doing this? Perhaps I am sending the IPI incorrectly?

Comment: I think you're sending the IPI correctly. Since Acknowledge interrupt on exit is 0, that's why the interrupt isn't posted in the ISR. The only way to find out the vector number is to enable interrupts in the kernel so the interrupt is delivered through the kernel IDT. The kernel interrupt handler for the vector then has to forward the interrupt to the guest.

Comment: I'm sure that Dune isn't mapping the physical APIC directly into the guest. That would definitely not qualify as "exposing privileged CPU features in a safe fashion." The APIC wouldn't know it is being accessed from a VM. The guest would be able to completely mess up the operation of the kernel.

Comment: The question says it maps "host physical base address of the memory-mapped APIC registers" into the guest, but your comment says "APIC page", which is correct.

Comment: @prl Ok, I'm going to keep reading about this and post some updates tomorrow. I am confused by your last two comments though. I agree that mapping the physical APIC directly into the guest would violate safety. However, it seems that since the Dune kernel module is setting the EPT such that the guest OS can write directly to the APIC's memory-mapped registers, safety is violated. Do you agree?

Comment: @prl I'm going to read more about vAPIC tomorrow, maybe this is what I really want? Based on your comment above, it seems that you want to me to add code to the host kernel's interrupt handlers, which I can't do through this module.

Comment: @prl Thanks for your help! This is my first time working with virtualization and Intel Vt-x, so I'm trying to figure everything out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159333/discussion-between-prl-and-jack-humphries).